# How do I get my browser to ignore certificate on trusted domain

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl-certificate

I got this message when I tried to login to my own dedi or one of the cpanel using Internet Explorer.

> The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a
> different website's address.

It's my site. I trusted it. How do I get rid that message?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: internet explorer.

Comment: "my own dedi" - is this a dedicated server?! If so then you should resolve the cert issue. If it's a shared server then it's common to share a cert across all sites, in which case you can access the generic domain the site is intended for.

Comment: What is the address in the certificate and what is the address of the site you are trying to connect to (replace your domain name with `example.com`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you go to Tools -> Internet Options, Advanced tab, and scroll to the bottom, you'll find an option to "Warn about certificate address mismatch", which you can disable; the change will take effect after you restart IE, and should stop the browser from complaining about the cert.

Unfortunately, it'll also stop the browser from complaining about address mismatches on every other site you visit, as well. That's less than ideal, but it's the kind of tradeoff you get to make when you use IE.

Of course, installing a cert with the right address on it (or, if it's a subdomain you're visiting and the cert's issued for a higher-level domain, a wildcard cert) would be the *right* answer, but if you can't do that, this will at least suppress the warning.

Comment: The certificate is for the main domain in the server. I tried to access cpanel on another domain under that main domain.

Comment: "That's less than ideal" - bit of an understatement. This is a serious security vulnerability and is not recommended.

Comment: I only use IE for my own site so this workaround is perfect for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should install the site's certificate into your local certificate store so your browser will then trust it.

I use self-signed SSL certs on development servers, so in each of my browsers I install the servers' certs. This also works for expired or mismatched "real" certificates.

Here's a link to do this in IE:
http://www.poweradmin.com/help/sslhints/ie.aspx